# How do I send an Array of [Double] via send multipeersession in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, send

I have var list: [Double] = [1.02, 0.97, ...] and I'm trying to send it to peers in the session.

I am using an Apple-provided template, so they already set up the received data function and a sendtoallpeers() function (below):

```
func sendToAllPeers(_ data: Data) {
        do {
            try session.send(data, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
        } catch {
            print("error sending data to peers: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

The received data handler is below:

```
func receivedData(_ data: Data, from peer: MCPeerID) {

    do {

        if let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: data) {

        } else
            if let anchor = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARAnchor.self, from: data) {


        } else if let list = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [Double].self, from: data) {




        }
```

This last part is where it fails, says "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'ofClass:from:', expected 'ofClasses:from:')"

How Apple structured the send functions for worldMap and anchor are as follows:

```
let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "basicBoard", transform: hitTestResultForLater!.worldTransform)
            guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: anchor, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                else { fatalError("can't encode anchor") }
            self.multipeerSession.sendToAllPeers(data)
```

How I structured sending the list:

```
guard let data2 = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: list, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        else { fatalError("can't encode list") }
    self.multipeerSession.sendToAllPeers(data2)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've been searching online all day for answers but cant find them. Can someone explain to me the correct way to send an array over multipeersession?

Comment: [Double] needs  to use (Classes:[AnyObject]:from:)  or comfort to  Decodable protocol/. and the list: [Double] needs to conform to  NSSecureCoding protocol.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. How would I make the list conform to NSSecureCoding Protocol?

Comment: I don't write such code before. You may check the document of `NSSecureCoding`